# Silverlight security exception on accessing wcf data service

Tags: silverlight-4.0, azure, wcf-data-services

I am making a silverlight application which uses a wcf data service which is deployed on cloud. The WCF data service works perfectly on the browser,however when I use it as a dataservice query to populate the controls and use the loadasync method i get the below error.

I included the clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml and it is accessible and open to all domains.

I used fiddler but it isn't even trying to retrieve the clientaccesspolicy.xml file rather  get the error before that.

Does anyone know how to find what is wrong at least?

e.Error
{System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClassd.<>c__DisplayClassf.<BeginLoadAsyncOperation>b__b()}
    [System.InvalidOperationException]: {System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<LoadAsync>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c_*DisplayClassd.<>c*_DisplayClassf.b_*b()}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    InnerException: {System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c*_DisplayClass5.b_*4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*1(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)}
    Message: "An error occurred while processing this request."
    StackTrace: "   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c*_DisplayClass2.b_*1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceCollection`1.<>c*_DisplayClassd.<>c_*DisplayClassf.b*_b()"

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. i changed my clientaccesspolicy.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<access-policy> 
  <cross-domain-access> 
    <policy> 
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*"> 
        <domain uri="*"/> 
      </allow-from> 
      <grant-to> 
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/> 
      </grant-to> 
    </policy> 
  </cross-domain-access> 
</access-policy>
```

after clearing the browser-cache my clientaccesspolicy got loaded and it works fine.
hope that helps

Comment: i forgot to mention, that i cleared my browser cache with fiddler. clearing with IE didn't resolve the problem.